# Find value by MethodName(String) in a LinqToSql result?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Let's say my Person class look like this:

```
Private Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
End Class
```

and I have a result called linqToSqlResult with name = "John" and Age = 30.
Now I want to get the Name of the person as follows:

```
Dim name As String = CStr(GetValue(linqResult, "Name"))
```

And I'm looking for some code like this:

```
Private Function GetValue(ByRef linqToSqlResult As Object, fieldName As String) As Object
    'Here's the code I'm looking for??
End Function
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the lack of information, I Assume the value passed as `LinqToSqlResult` is the ouput of the query of the type `Person`, If not please explain more clearly the `contents of LinqToSqlResult`

What you could do is the following (Not the most performant piece of code though):

```
Imports System.Reflection


Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim i As Object = New Person With {.Name = "TestUser", .Age = 30}
        Console.WriteLine(GetValue(Of Person)(i, "Name").ToString())
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(GetValue(Of Person)(i, "Age").ToString()))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub


    Private Function GetValue(Of T)(ByRef linqToSqlResult As Object, fieldName As String) As Object
        Dim myProp As PropertyInfo = GetType(T).GetProperties().Where(Function(x) x.Name.Equals(fieldName)).FirstOrDefault()
        If (myProp IsNot Nothing) Then
            Return myProp.GetValue(linqToSqlResult, Nothing)
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException(" Some usefull message")
        End If
    End Function


End Module


Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As String
End Class
```

This outputs:

```
//TestUser
//30
```

Comment: ABSOLUTELY PERFECT!  ... That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for helping me out - you literally saved my day!! :)